# I want a square to take any extra space above it in there is any

Tags: html, css

let's say I have a function that display squares for this example 8 squares, the squares display 4 of them in a line in the middle of the page, so 4 square then another 4 below them, I want like square 7 to display below square 3 but square 3 have short height so square 7 will take the empty space below square 3.

I just want to know how to make the square take the empty space above them and they should have a little gap between them, the example is not important.

here an example code

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: auto;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: start;
}

.square {
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="square" style="height: 100px;"></div>
  <div class="square" style="height: 120px;"></div>
  <div class="square" style="height: 80px;"></div>
  <div class="square" style="height: 110px;"></div>
  <div class="square" style="height: 90px;"></div>
  <div class="square" style="height: 100px;"></div>
  <div class="square" style="height: 130px;"></div>
  <div class="square" style="height: 70px;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: It sounds like you are describing a "mosaic" or "masonry" layout, which is a pretty widely discussed topic here if you want to search using those terms.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [css only masonry layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44377343/css-only-masonry-layout)